# React Native Navigator: Can I remove navigation gestures from a scene after a user action?

Tags: react-native, navigator

I want to disable the swipe from left pop gesture on the navigator after the side menu has been accessed within a scene. I don't want to disable it when the scene first renders, only when the side menu is open. I have an `onOpen` function I can call, but I don't know how to programatically change the navigation gestures without pushing another route.

I tried setting the configureScene prop of the navigator like this:

`configureScene={() => {
    return this.state.swipeBackNavigation ? FloatFromRight : Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
}`

and changing the state, but the component doesn't rerender

ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just set gestures to null (effectively disabling it):

`gestures: {}`

I can't test this currently, but I suspect it will work (if I didn't screw up some syntax somewhere):

```
export default class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        //initialize gestureChoice
        gestureChoice: {},
      }
  }

  disablePop(){  
    setState({ gestureChoice:{ gestures:{} } });
  }
  enablePop(){  
    setState({gestureChoice: ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Navigator
        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
          return <SomeScene navigator={navigator} {...route.passprops} />
        }
        configureScene={(route, routeStack) =>
          this.state.gestureChoice;
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The idea being, you could use `enablePop()` and `disablePop()` whenever you would like.

This thread is probably helpful: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1014

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tried this. This does remove gestures, but is only effective once a new route has been pushed to the navigator, I wanted something that would disable it w/o pushing a new route. If there were some way of reloading the navigator config while staying on the same route this would work